# MongoDB Reactive Streams hangs when performing a query

Tags: java, mongodb, reactive-streams

I'm using the MongoDB Reactive Streams Java API which I implemented following [this example](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/blob/master/examples/tour/src/main/tour/SubscriberHelpers.java), but I'm encountering a serious problem: sometimes, when I try to query a collection, the `await` methods doesn't work, and it hangs until the timeout is reached.

The `onSubscribe` methods gets called correctly, but then neither `onNext`, nor `onError` nor `onComplete` get called.

There doesn't seem to be a specific circumstance causing this issue.

This is my code

```
MongoDatabase database = MongoDBConnector.getClient().getDatabase("myDb");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("myCollection");
FindPublisher<Document> finder = collection.find(Filters.exists("myField"));    
SettingSubscriber tagSub = new SettingSubscriber(finder); 
//SettingsSubscriber is a subclass of ObservableSubscriber which calls publisher.subscribe(this)
tagSub.await(); //this is where it hangs
return tagSub.getWrappedData();
```

Comment: `publisher#subscribe(subscriber)`, is missing. See the [Quick Tour - MongoDB Reactive Streams Java Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/1.13/getting-started/quick-tour/). Also, see [org.reactivestreams.Publisher's subscribe()](http://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.3-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Publisher.html).

Comment: @prasad_ Actually it is there (see the comment on the 5th line of code). Also, as I said, `onSubscribe` always gets called.

Comment: @gscaparrotti How many documents are present in the collection `myCollection`? The exists check on `myField` will perform a full collection scan. If there are a lot of records in the collection, the query is probably timing out

Comment: There are less than 100 documents, and the timeout is one minute, so I don't think this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple implementation of what I assumed the `SettingSubscriber` looked like and tried to recreate the problem using a groovy script. I couldn't - my code runs without hanging, prints each output record and exits. Code for reference below:

```
@Grab(group = 'org.mongodb', module = 'mongodb-driver-reactivestreams', version = '4.3.3')
@Grab(group = 'org.slf4j', module = 'slf4j-api', version = '1.7.32')
@Grab(group = 'ch.qos.logback', module = 'logback-classic', version = '1.2.6')

import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.FindPublisher;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.reactivestreams.Subscriber;
import org.reactivestreams.Subscription;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

MongoClientSettings.Builder clientSettingsBuilder = MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .applyToClusterSettings { clusterSettingsBuilder ->
            clusterSettingsBuilder.hosts( Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017)))
        };
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(clientSettingsBuilder.build());
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("myDb");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("myCollection");
FindPublisher<Document> finder = collection.find(Filters.exists("myField"));
SettingSubscriber tagSub = new SettingSubscriber(finder);
tagSub.await();

class SettingSubscriber implements Subscriber<Document> {
    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private Subscription subscription;
    private List<Document> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public SettingSubscriber(FindPublisher<Document> finder) {
        finder.subscribe(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(final Subscription subscription) {
        this.subscription = subscription;
        subscription.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(final Document document) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + document);
        data.add(document);
        subscription.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(final Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
        latch.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        System.out.println("Completed");
        latch.countDown();
    }
    
    public List<Document> getWrappedData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void await() throws Throwable {
        await(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public void await(final long timeout, final TimeUnit unit) throws Throwable {
        if (!latch.await(timeout, unit)) {
            System.out.println("Publish timed out");
        }
    }
}
```

Can you compare this implementation of the `SettingSubscriber` with yours to see if something is missed?

Comment: The only difference I see is that I don't call `subscription.request(1)` in `onNext`

Comment: Are you doing something like `subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE)` once in the `onSubscribe` method instead? The `subscription.request` call needs to be made somewhere, either for all results in one shot like `subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE)` or for fewer results at a time like `subscription.request(1)`

Comment: I do it in the `onSubscribe` method. What happens if I request only a small amount of items once and the publisher wants to send more?

Comment: That's what the `subscription.request` call in `onNext` method is for, to request more items after we receive an item

Comment: I get this. I wonder what happens if the Publisher has more available items than the requested amount.

Comment: I think the subscriber wouldn't receive the additional items unless it requests for them